# Show that the subset of $[0,1]$ of numbers in base expansion 5 is Lebesgue-measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The complete statement of the exercise is as follows:

For $ I = [0,1]$, let be $ A \subseteq I $ the subset of points $ x \in I$ whose base 5 expansion has the form: $$ x = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x_k}{5^k} $$

where $x_k \in \{0,4\}$. Show that the set $A$ is Lebesgue-Measurable and $m(A) = 0$.

I have a question about the exercise:

Is not true that all numbers in $ [0,1] $ has  a 5 base expansion? In that case $I = A$ but that would contradicts the exercise becasue $m(A) =  m(I) = 1$ so what us happening here?

Now my attempt to solve:

Because we already assume that $m(A) = 0$ so it is enough to show that $m^{*}(A) = 0$ and this happens if $A$ is countable, and this happensi if there is a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

and that is, some idea to proceed?

Comment: Yes, all numbers in $[0,1]$ have a base $5$ expansion. However "most" of these base $5$ expansions use the digits $1$, $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the set $A$ is uncountable. so you should find another idea.

Comment: @uniquesolution how do you know that the set $A$ is uncountable?

Comment: @JoséMarín Because there is an injective map from the set of all infinite sequences consisting of zero or one into $A$. I suggest you look up the Cantor set, and see how is it proved there that it has measure $1$.